# Problem in loading Data to Treelist in DevXpress using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have problem in loading data to treelist of DevXpress in .Net platform(VB.Net) so can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: This question is comically incomplete

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Treelist demos on the Devexpress website](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/) which have several worked examples. Note that your data source must contain hierarchical information so that the treelist knows where to put each item in the hierarchy.